# Get first and last records in a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Id1 and Id2 with different STime and ETime. For each group of Id1 and Id2, I tend to get the first and last record (as shown in the output).
I tried partitioning the table with Id1 and Id2 and order it by asc and desc order using:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.HardwareId, A.TripId ORDER BY StartTime) AS first_record,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.HardwareId, A.TripId ORDER BY StopTime DESC) AS last_record
```

I did not get the results as expected.

```
SELECT
    A.Id1 AS Id1,
    A.Id2 AS TriId2pId,
    STime,
    ETime,
    Latitude,
    Longitude

FROM
    Tr.T1 AS A
JOIN
    Tp.G2 AS B
ON
    A.STime < B.DateTime
    AND A.ETime >= B.DateTime
    AND A.Id1 = B.Id1
WHERE
  (A._PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-11-23')
    AND TIMESTAMP('2016-11-23')
    AND A.Id1 IN (976))
ORDER BY
   B.Id1,
   A.Id2,
   B.DateTime 



    Id1 Id2 STime               ETime               Latitude    Longitude
    976 715 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:23:30 26.2230015  -80.12314    
    976 715 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:23:30 26.2229767  -80.12326    
    976 715 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:23:30 26.2226944  -80.12344
    976 800 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:24:59 26.2251511  -80.11865    
    976 800 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:24:59 26.2251511  -80.11912    
    976 800 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:24:59 26.2250233  -80.11929    
    976 800 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:24:59 26.2245369  -80.11929        


    Id1 Id2 STime               ETime               Latitude    Longitude
    976 715 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:23:30 26.2230015  -80.12314
    976 715 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:23:30 26.2226944  -80.12344
    976 800 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:24:59 26.2251511  -80.11865
    976 800 2016-11-23 13:06:26 2016-11-23 13:24:59 26.2245369  -80.11929
```

Comment: first and last for each Id or for whole output?

Comment: I am trying it for each Id

Comment: and what is `first` and `last`? is it based on which exactly field?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve first and last records for each hardwareId.

Comment: 1). hardwareId is not even in your oputput - you should correct your question respectivelly; 2) what is your definition of FIRST and LAST record? is it based on some time field? or something else?

Comment: that didn't helped much - but, still  - try my answer - should work

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant:  have edited my question, i tried your solution, getting the error "Window framing clause is not allowed for analytic function row_number
"

Comment: edited. check again. don't have chance to test so writing on-fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query in your original question does not exactly match you later comments, but still below should help you to make your goal

Try

```
SELECT
   A.Id AS Id,
   StartTime,
   StopTime,
   Latitude,
   Longitude
FROM (
  SELECT
   A.Id AS Id,
   StartTime,
   StopTime,
   Latitude,
   Longitude,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY StartTime) AS first_record,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS last_record
  FROM
   Tb1.Ids  AS A
  JOIN
   Tb2.Points AS B
  ON
   A.StartTime <= B.DateTime
   AND A.StopTime >= B.DateTime
   AND A.HardwareId = B.HardwareId
  WHERE
   (A._PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-11-23')
    AND TIMESTAMP('2016-11-23'))
   AND A.Id IN (334)
)
WHERE first_record = 1 OR last_record = 1
```

Idea here to add two fields in inner query that would numbering all rows from start and from end

```
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY StartTime ) AS first_record,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS last_record
```

and than to leave the first and respectively last rows

```
WHERE first_record = 1 OR last_record = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the desired result when i partitioned it based on Id1 and Id2.

Comment: but your original question was just with Id1 and not with two Ids!! Isn't two Ids your new question? i was about to answer it?

Comment: can you clarify if you get desired output on your original question with just one ID?

Comment: Since, partition with Id1 did not work, I tried by adding Id2 in the partition.

Comment: ok, i didn't get this but hope someone else will be able to help. please note  - totally changing your question is not how it works on SO, especially after you already accepted it for original version!!  if you have new question - you should ask that new one and stick with it. but not go back to old one and re-write it making old answer not relevant anymore. just my suggestion for you if you expect people here to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of that, will ask mine as a new question. Thank you